# How do I see turn server logs?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I am working on a video conferencing app using webRtc. I have configured coturn as turn server. How do I see logs of turn server when a client uses it?

Answer (score 3):

The default path to the log is: /var/log/turn_*.log

Answer (score 3):

How did you start your turn server? Start coturn server in verbose mode by adding -v option like `turnserver -v`. By default, all log files will be stored at /var/tmp/ location. File name format is **turn_pid_yyyy-mm-dd.log** where pid is process id. Sample log file name is turn_16996_2019-10-15.log.